# Deleting multiple sub directories with in multiple directories

Tags: command-line

I have a got a list of directories which have three sub directories in each of them.I want to delete the all the three sub directories located in each of the directory in the list with a single command.
Suppose "~Documents/Directory" is the path to the "Directory" folder mentioned in the path which contains 100 folders with each folder having three sub folders namely 1,2,3.I want to delete 1,2,3 of all the 100 folders
with a single command.

Comment: So there are not other directories, just those three?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This should work <sup>always test safely dangerous commands</sup>:

```
cd ~/Documents/Directory
find . -maxdepth 2 -mindepth 2 -type d -exec rm -rf {} +
```

Comment: Thank you very much.It's cool.

Answer (score 1):

You have to use the following command:

For 1 subfolder:

```
sudo rm -Rf Path/to/Directory/*/Subfolder\ 01
```

For 3 subfolders:

```
sudo rm -Rf Path/to/Directory/*/Subfolder\ 01 Directory/*/Subfolder\ 02 Directory/*/Subfolder\ 03
```

Note that I wrote `Subfolder 01` with this syntax: `Subfolder\ 01`. For a reason I ignore, Terminal accepts only the second syntax (and do not put quotation marks around the path).